# Scrapy: Traverse through subcategories

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping a website of supplier. This supplier has products divided into categories and subcategories. The problem is that not all products have subcategories but all products are in categories.

So for example:

```
category1
  product1
  product2
  product3
  subcategory1
    product1
    product2
```

As you can see **product3** isn't in subcategory. It's only in **category1** and **products 2 and 3** are in category but they are in **subcategory1** too.

I'm working on a spider which will use `XMLItemExporter` and I want every product to be in XML only once - with it's most specific category.

So I want output:

```
product1 - category1>subcategory1
product2 - category1>subcategory1
product3 - category1
```

I have to traverse through categories because products has no category mentioned in their detail `url` and I want to have information about their category and subcategory.

I can't do this:

```
scrape category - scrape all products - scrape subcategory - scrape all products
```

Because I would have products from subcategory scraped with category only so there will be duplicates in XML.

Do you have any idea how to make this work?

EDIT: Possible solution? Don't know if I can force scrapy to scrape one type of links before another. I yes, I would get all subcategories urls, scrape products from these subcategories and then scrape all categories. If there were already scraped product, I would skipped it.

Comment: From your example it seems to me that product3 has indeed a subcategory contrary to what you write.

Comment: @mrCarnivore I don't understand. See the example - p1,p2,p3 are in category1, but as you can see, subcategory1 contains only product1 an product2

Comment: Your edit solved the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I would have implemented this in three steps:

1. The first step would build a complete list of item URLs with corresponding categories and subcategories in which they were found.
2. I would then implement some logic on this list to make sure that only the most specific (i.e deepest) category were used.
3. The cleaned list of URLs would then be  fed to the second step scraper that would scrape the actual item data.

More strategy than coding, but hope it helps.

In summary: crawl -> clean -> scrape